# C# win form app not working outside rar file

Tags: c#, excel, debugging, c#-4.0, interop

I have really strange 'bug' that I don't have a clue what it might be about.
App is made with VS2010 using .net 4 frame. Beside normal assemblies, it uses MS inter-op for excel. I have Office 2010 installed on client machine.

Basically, app parse excel sheet and makes another one (new file) with results.
Problem: when I copy an exe file to the desktop (or anywhere else on PC) it is throwing exception, but when it is in archive (RAR) and archive is on the desktop it is working perfectly.

I can't install it due they have very restrictive system (telephone company) and that app shouldn't be used at all. (Worker who is parsing it manually, usually takes 3 hours to do it while program does it in 5 sec, so the boss cant know about it, because he thinks they are all hardworking :) ).

The problem persists on other machines within company so it isn't isolated case.

Any info about it would be APPRECIATED. P.S. If any more info is needed gimme a shout. Here is 'detail' of unhandled exception.

See the end of this message for details on invoking just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

> ************** Exception Text **************
>       System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>       Parameter name: length
>          at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
>          at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>          at ExcelSvjetlana.Form1.buttonObradi_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ```
> ************** Loaded Assemblies **************
> mscorlib
>     Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.239 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> ExcelSvjetlana
>     Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/sobradovic/Desktop/Interno.exe
> ----------------------------------------
> System.Windows.Forms
>     Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> System.Drawing
>     Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.276 built by: RTMGDR
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> System
>     Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.258 built by: RTMGDR
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> System.Data
>     Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> System.Core
>     Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> System.Xml
>     Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> System.Numerics
>     Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
>    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
>     Assembly Version: 14.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 14.0.4756.1000
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> office
>     Assembly Version: 14.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 14.0.4760.1000
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/office/14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/office.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> Microsoft.CSharp
>     Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.CSharp/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.CSharp.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> System.Dynamic
>     Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Dynamic/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Dynamic.dll
> ----------------------------------------
> Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
>     Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
>     Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.239 (RTMGDR.030319-2300)
>     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
> ----------------------------------------
>
> ************** JIT Debugging **************
> To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
> application or computer (machine.config) must have the
> jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
> The application must also be compiled with debugging
> enabled.
> ```

```
For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

And here is that code u asked for. Take note that i did change some strings.

```
private void buttonObradi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int brojac = 0;
    string grade = "";
    string grading1 = "2";
    string grading2 = "3";
    string grading3 = "4";
    string grading4 = "1";
    string grading5 = "No Answer";
    string grading6 = "5";
    string grupa = "";
    bool citaj = false;
    bool mozda = false;
    string odjel = "";
    string pododjel = "";
    string ocjenica = "";
    int prviProlaz = 0;

    foreach (DataRow redak in excelData.Rows)
    {
        if (prviProlaz > 0)
        {
            if (brojac == 0)
            {
                brojac = 1;
                grupa = redak[1].ToString();
                mozda = false;
                citaj = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (redak[1].ToString() == "")
                {
                    mozda = true;
                    citaj = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (redak[1].ToString() == "Agent Name")
                    {
                        citaj = true;
                    }
                    else if (redak[1].ToString() == grading1 || redak[1].ToString() == grading2 || redak[1].ToString() == grading3 || redak[1].ToString() == grading4 || redak[1].ToString() == grading5 || redak[1].ToString() == grading6)
                    {
                        grade = redak[1].ToString();
                        mozda = false;
                    }
                    else if (mozda == true)
                    {
                        brojac = 0;
                    }
                    else if (citaj == true)
                    {
                        if (grupa == "Team A" || grupa == "Team M" || grupa == "Team T")
                        {
                            pododjel = "AAAA";
                            odjel = "CCCC";
                        }
                        else if (grupa == "Team 1" || grupa == "Team 2")
                        {
                            pododjel = "BBBB";
                            odjel = "TTTT";
                        }
                        else if (grupa == "K Team" || grupa == "F Team")
                        {
                            pododjel = "RRRR";
                            odjel = "SSSS";
                        }
                        else if (grupa == "Group 1" || grupa == "Group 2" || grupa == "Group 3" || grupa == "Group 4")
                        {
                            pododjel = "FFFF";
                            odjel = "TTTTT";
                        }
                        else if (grupa == "Fun group 1" || grupa == "fun group 2" || grupa == "fun group 3" || grupa == "fun group 4" || grupa == "fun group 5")
                        {
                            pododjel = "KKKK";
                            odjel = "FFFF";
                        }
                        ocjenica = ocjenica.Trim();

                        preSort.Rows.Add(redak[0].ToString(), redak[1].ToString(), "", grade, Convert.ToDecimal(redak[4].ToString()), grade.Substring(0, 1), grupa, pododjel, odjel);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            prviProlaz = 1;
        }
    }
    dataGridView2.DataSource = preSort;
}
```

Comment: I think you are using some **String** function which has a wrong argument value, either the index is wrong or the length is more than it should be.
there or some simillar part of code:
`String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)`

Comment: Show us the code for buttonObradi_Click.

Comment: yeah, show us the code....!!!

Comment: Ill post code when i come back from work, but i doubt it is much of relevance when it is working perfectly on my machine, my office machine or where ever i tested it (beside pointed company)

Comment: The actual code that generates this error is required to help.

Comment: fact is that i do not think the code is generating an error, but non the less i posted the code that was asked in the comment.

Comment: Hi @GustavKlimt, is there any reason why my answer isn't correct after all this time? Is this code playing up again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i got it. It was due to priveleges. Rar had it, while my aplication wasnt installed and was without privelege to folders. Hence the error occured. 
Still donno why any of method would use mem space on disk.

As i said, it isnt a problem with String functions.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have appears to be a `Substring` operation with invalid parameters. That's the error anyway.

What is that line of code doing in `buttonObradi_Click`? Maybe the problem you have is because of a false relative path to the file you want to open. Or the path of your exe, more likely. Like, you search for the fourth backslash and do a `Substring` from there... if your exe is in a path with less than 4 backslashes, you're in trouble :) Just an example.

**EDIT**:
fact is, `Substring` does generate an error, and the only substring in you code is `grade.Substring(0, 1)`. So grade has to be empty. You say this happens only on some machines, so my guess is, the excell on that machine is formatted differently. 
As far as I can determine from the code, you parse the excell expecting the row with the `grade` to come before that with "Agent Name".
This if:

```
else if (redak[1].ToString() == grading1 || redak[1].ToString() == grading2 || redak[1].ToString() == grading3 || redak[1].ToString() == grading4 || redak[1].ToString() == grading5 || redak[1].ToString() == grading6)
```

has to pass first and initialize the grade, before this line:

```
if (redak[1].ToString() == "Agent Name")
```

sets your `citaj` to true. Otherwise your `grade` variable is never initialized and of course the Substring fails.

I hope I understood that correctly, I haven't really debugged the whole code. 
So I think you should check the excells on the machines this is not working, see if they are wrong or you need to adjust your code to match that formatting too. 
But I still don't understand why this would work from the RAR and not outside of it....

Comment: ill give you +1 for pointer, but my main concern is the RAR issue, and lack of info that i cant get why the problem is occuring.

Comment: @GustavKlimt The **Edit** is the answer to your problem as you use `SubString` once in the button_click and the stacktrace tells us thats the error. You cant rely on apps working from RAR archives - sounds like its somehow masking the error.  *BTW I'd hate to be in your shoes when management finds out you've put their secure network at risk by installing software behind their back*. Talk to them and do it properly -> add a Setup Project to your VS2010 solution and Package & Deploy the windows app correctly.

Comment: I dont see it, grade is initialized by "", so it does exist. It is being populated few lines after. And that never fails due it is drawing reports from report tool. If that would be the case, i belive the app would throw exception while on my desktop/laptop (without deploy/install). but that case isnt happening. I allready tryed to change SubString, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Ok can you post the Excel Data Source and indicate the row of the spreadsheet that causes the problem? Ta

Comment: well, i can only guess that due i cant install VS on machine and debug. The report is usually 30-50k row long. I can spam you on your mail (shorted version coz format pattern is repeating) if you really, really want to pop an eye on it.

Comment: Put the `foreach(DataRow redak` in a `Try-Catch`. Then declare a variable `dr` thats scope is beyond the `try-catch` and assign `redak` to `dr` each iteration. Then in the `try-catch` Exception Handler spit out the details of the excel spreadsheet `dr` line so you can trace it and reproduce it in the debugger.

Comment: Thx, will try it after xmas, and tell chick at operator to try it. Please do post an answer so i can award you a points if the solution is in SubString handling.

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace leads us to see the error pertains to the Obradi button click invoking the `Substring` method incorrectly (probably because the string is null):

```
System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
at ExcelSvjetlana.Form1.buttonObradi_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The error message allows us to see its a `OutOFRange` exception and the start/stop string extract is a problem:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a
>   location within the string.

When we examine the use of `grade.substring` we can see its state maybe empty, null or etc. (afaik its null).

**Solution**

When adding rows to the datatable to bind to dataGridView2 put a [conditional break point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx) on this line to ensure the grade string variable is not `string.IsNullOrEmpty(grade)`:

```
preSort.Rows.Add(redak[0].ToString(), redak[1].ToString(), "", grade, Convert.ToDecimal(redak[4].ToString()), grade.Substring(0, 1), grupa, pododjel, odjel);
```

When you cannot reproduce the problem in your local development environment you need to add logging and exception handling.

Put the `foreach(DataRow redak` in a Try-Catch. Then declare a variable `dr` thats scope is beyond the try-catch and assign `redak` to `dr` each iteration. Then in the try-catch Exception Handler spit out the details of the excel spreadsheet `dr` line so you can trace it and reproduce it in the debugger, eg:

```
    DataRow dr;
    try
    {
       foreach (DataRow redak in excelData.Rows)
       {
          dr = redak;
       ...
       }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         WriteToLog("Event: buttonObradi_Click. Problem with importing excel spreadsheet row: " + dr[0].ToString() + "\r\n Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you double click on a .exe file inside a rar, (inside winrar or 7zip), all of the rar file contents gets extracted in a new folder in the local temp folder, a folder like this:
C:\Users\~ user name ~\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$EX00.744\

So you need to check this folder, and see what files might be there that helps running the application.

It could be loading a different excel file, you haven't shared that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you call `Substring()` with wrong parameters — maybe `startIndex` is too small or too large. Or it is `length` which is too large (or too small). .NET implementation of `Substring` always bugged me — I'd rather have it return `string.Empty` instead of throwing; so you may insert checks before `Substring()` call or...

```
public static string SubstringFixed(this string str, int startIndex, int length)
{
    if (startIndex >= str.length || startIndex < 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    length = Math.Min(length, str.Length - startIndex);
    length = Math.Max(length, 0);

    return str.Substring(startIndex, length);
}
```

Declare this method somewhere in an utility class, and just use `s.SubstringFixed()` instead of `s.Substring` — it will just return `""` instead of throwing `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in bad cases.

Oh, and of course, when you work with strings you should always be sure you treat empty strings correctly... whatever "correctly" may stand for. Usually it's just "don't crash and do actually nothing".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this issue is because of something wrong in the code.

Please make sure that you are not having an excel file(or any other file) inside the archive(RAR) which is used by the code.

Comment: Before reading, log/debug complete file path (of the excel file you are reading).

FileInfo fileInfo= new FileInfo(fileName);
fileInfo.DirectoryName; //This line will give you the complete path

Then check what is the file that is getting used in your approaches

Comment: File is fine, it is used wich openFileDialog control. And the file is being copy pasted to datatable.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned this issue with you calling on grade.Substring(0,1) while grade is an empty string. 
There's no question about it, it's the only call to this method in your code that can raise this exception. You should definitely surround this method with a Try Catch block to gracefully fail.

In your code, when grade is empty, I.E length 0 and you're trying to access the grade[0] which will raise an exception.

ToDecimal will also raise an exception if the input is malformed, so you need to gracefully check the input for that too. Again, a Try Catch block will do wonders and allow your program to keep running while only missing this one row.

If this was an issue with the EXE after extraction from the RAR file you would have a corrupt executable. I'm not sure how your application loads an excel file, but you might have a correct excel file in the temp folder if it automatically tries to load one from current directory (this is where your EXE is when you execute from the RAR file)